# Relation between lossy decomposition and Natural join?

Tags: database-design, join

[image]

I am confused with the lossy decomposition and natural join. Natural join(with common attribute): only respective common attribute for the resultant table is formed. Lossy: Natural join on tables with common attribute results formation of spurious table. the problem is, both have common attribute but showing 2 different solutions.one is showing original tuple other a spurious tuple.

Please Help.

I've seen these articles:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671362/lossy-decomposition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548543/natural-join-if-no-common-attrubute http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Natural_join_.28.E2.8B.88.29